# LG K4 K120E Unrooted after an update and won't root again

Tags: rooting, lg

I have rooted my LG K4 K120E (2016) a long time ago using KingRoot, however after the phone got an update the phone was unrooted and KingRoot just won't work anymore. What would be the safest rooting method for my phone without loosing data?

EDIT: Tried kingroot and kingoroot again and got a ram dump screen (like BSOD) but the phone is ok

Comment: Don't ever update rooted phone, or you can get result like this or worse, and avoid one click root apps (kingroot etc). What you can do is to try to flash newest firmware and try to root, if it fails that means that version isn't rootable, in that case flash firmware you had when you successfully rooted phone and root it and do not update it.

Comment: So you mean that I can't get root on my phone without losing all the data? I've seen some pre-rooted ROMs for the phone on XDA, but I think they are outdated (2016-01-01).

Comment: Well if you use that ROM you will lose all data anyway.

Comment: All root methods I could find are either one-click or a rom. How can I root the phone normally? Like can I root using ADB or something? @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out! The update added an OEM lock to the phone (I think) so I had to disable it in the settings! I've been poking through the settings and randomly discovered an OEM lock there. I looked it up and turns out I had to disable it before rooting the phone. So I have disabled the OEM lock (I don't need it anyway) and I am going to try to root the phone again when I come back!